# Overriding protected variables between parent and child classes

Tags: php

```
abstract class BaseController
{
    protected $arctica, $database, $content, $cacheTime;

    function __construct($arctica)
    {
        $this->arctica = $arctica;
        $this->config = $arctica->config;
        $this->database = $arctica->database;
    }

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $cacheTime = 2;
    protected $database = 'override'; //trying to override database var

    function __construct($arctica)
    {
        parent::__construct($arctica);
    }

    function Run()
    {
                    var_dump($this->database); //A class instance, not string('override')
        $this->load('homepage');
    }
}
```

I'd like to ask few things about this class.

**Q1:** If I want to reach `$database variable of child class`, how can I reach it?

**Q2:** How can I ensure `$database variable in parent class` can't be changed/overridden by child class, even in self? ($database should be a constant holding database instance so Controller child shouldn't touch it.) Right now it is like that, but I don't know why tbh.

**Q3:** How can I add more parameters to my created variables? Like, instead of protected $var  `protected const $var` would have more meaning to me. Is it something just PHP doesn't support, or not supported in OOP at all? (Maybe it is supported and I don't know how?)

**Q4:** If I define a method in parent class, can I reach it without $this? Like `load('homepage')`.

Thanks alot!

Comment: Q1: From where ? From parent to child?

Comment: Take a look at final: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: Q3: How could a protected non static constant be usefull?

Comment: @jantimon He's talking about attributes, so I'm afraid that `final` won't to anything here.

Comment: After reading your Questions and comments to the answers I've come to the conclusion that you should really read something about OOP. It does not necessarily has to be about PHP but about OOP in general. Could start with wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Design_patterns and continue with something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep

Comment: I appreciate your advise @Joshua, but I'm trying to develop a basic framework mostly for educational purposes. I'm trying to learn oop by practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code takes the database information out of the `$arctica` object. The info there is used, neither the protected variable in the abstract class nor the extended class.

If you want the protected variable to survive, you must create your own version of `__construct()` to change this. Probably like this:

```
public function __construct($arctica) {
    parent::__construct($arctica);
    $this->database = "override";
}
```

Q1: You do reach it.

Q2: Impossible to enforce with a protected variable. Simply do not code stuff that does this. You can use getters and setters to achieve this.

Q3: PHP does not support this.

Q4: No. PHP always needs `$this` if used inside objects to work on it's own instance.

Comment: You're correct about Q1. I completely forgot about passing values inside constructor. All my questions are answered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: If I want to reach $database variable of child class, how can I reach it?

If it's declared `protected`, you access it with `$this->database` from either parent or child.

If it's `private`, you access it through `$this->database`, but only from parent.

> Q2: How can I ensure $database variable in parent class can't be changed/overridden by child class, even in self?

You can declare it `private`. However, in my opinion, using `private` is a code smell. You should rather make them two separate classes and combine them through composition.

> Q3: How can I add more parameters to my created variables?

No idea what you mean.

> Q4: If I define a method in parent class, can I reach it without $this? Like load('homepage').

You can't. That's how PHP works.

Comment: Q3: It's basically instead of public $var, public var $var or public const $var.

Comment: You mean you want to make a constant? Use the `const` keyword then.

Comment: No. Let's say, public (means the variable is public) integer (means the variable is integer) $variable. So variable should both be integer and public, not integer alone. I can create const keyword to create a variable, but then, how can I give it public/private/protected keywords?

Comment: Well `const`'s are always public, that's true. And you can't specify a type for a variable, since PHP doesn't have a static type system. PHP looks superficially like Java, but it's quite different in some respects.

Answer (score 0):

**A1**: `BaseController` can't reach attributes of its child classes. `BaseController` doesn't even know that it has children. You can make it `abstract` and force its children to implement a getter so that `BaseController` can access attribute values through the getter.

**A2**: Make `database` in `BaseController` `private` so that only `BaseController` can access it. Then define a protected getter in `BaseController` so that child classes can access `database` through the getter and not directly.

**A3**: PHP does not have keywords like `final` as Java has it for example. PHP knows the keyword `const` but this has a different meaning than "once written never written again". Look up the manual for `const`.

**A4**: Nope, language restrictions again. Without `$this` PHP would not know that you want to access a method or property. You could want to access a global function or a local variable (which would be created).

Comment: Your A1 isn't correct. `BaseController` can most certainly access attributes of its children.

Comment: A2: Controller also has to access $database variable in BaseController, but Controller shouldn't re-define $database variable in itself. I don't want people to re-define $database variable in child class and appoint a value to it. They should be permitted cause $database should only work with a valid database instance.

Comment: @troelskn Hard to believe for me, but ok - I'll do some research.

Comment: @LisaMiskovsky Changed my A2